# Handsontable, can't set col width

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I'm doing a jsp web app to SMS services. Basically there's a data grid with two columns: [Message, Number]
The problem I've been facing is that when I write a long text the width of the cell expands with the text.
I tried setting the colWidth with wordWrap false, but none of that worked.
Here is my code:

```
var data = [ [ "", "" ], [ "", "" ], [ "", "" ], [ "", "" ],[ "", "" ], [ "", "" ], [ "", "" ], [ "", "" ],
                        [ "", "" ],[ "", "" ], [ "", "" ] ];
                    console.log("Data: " + data);
                    $("#dataTable").handsontable({
                        data : data,
                        manualRowMove: true,
                        startRows : 6,
                        startCols : 8,
                        width: '100%',
                        height : 'auto',
                        minSpareRows : 2,
                        rowHeaders : true,
                        maxRows: 50,
                        colHeaders : [ 'Mensaje', 'Número' ],
                        colWidths: [150, 150],
                        manualColumnResize: true    
                    });
```

I need the cells to be a certain width and not expand if I write a long text.

Answer (score 0):

In this example you set up 150 pixels for the first column (even when text takes less space) and the same for the 2nd column. If you have more than two columns they will expand with the text and if empty should have 50px per columns. Now in the demo https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-sea-9woqvm?file=/src/index.js we can see that when a longer text is added the cell expand but vertically, horizontally it has a maximum of 150 pixels.

If you'd rather have a cell that does not expand at all (vertically as well) you'd need to create a custom cell renderer that cuts the text visually (it will be fully accessible by the cell editor when the user edits a cell). To do that you'd need to wrap the TD element in a DIV with fixed pixel dimensions. Then you can also add the CSS ellipsis.